# How can I make my submit button add the values to my cart table

Tags: php, html, sql, heidisql

I'm trying to get the "Cart_View02" table to update when the submit button is clicked. I'm new to php and sql this semester. Anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

```
<?PHP
 if (isset($_GET['tab'])) $table= $_GET['tab'];
 else $table="Cart_view02";
$reset = true;
$errmsg = array("","");
//1. Make a connection to the database
$dbconn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","mydatabase1") 
      or die(mysqli_connect_error());
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    $action = $_POST['action']; 
    $qty = $_POST['txtqty'];
    $crtnum = $_POST[100];
    $itemid = $_POST[$row[0]];
        if($action == "select"){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO cart_lineitems VALUES ($crtnum, '$itemid',
'$qty');";
        $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql) or die(mysql_error($db));
        }
//print_r($_POST);
header("location: cartdump.php");
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Order Page</title>
<link href="css/styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>

<img class="banner" src="Images/acme_banner.jpg" alt="Acme Spook Shoppe"/>

</head>
<body> 
<br><br> 
<a href= "home.php">Home</a>

<form name="form1" method='POST'>
<?php
if (isset($_GET['prod'])) $prod=$_GET['prod'];
else $prod = "arm01";
//echo $prod;   //<------To print results



$sql = "select productid,name,imagefile, "
    ."shortdescription, longdescription,"
    ."unitprice "
    ."from products "
    ."where productid='$prod'";
    echo "<br>";
//echo $sql;    //<------To print results

//2. Run a query against the database
$result = mysqli_query($dbconn,$sql) 
    or die(mysqli_error($dbconn));

    //print_r($result); //<------To print results

//3. Return the results
    echo "<table class=ordertable >";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>$row[1]<br><br>";
    echo "$row[3]<br><br>";
    echo "$row[4]<br><br>";
    echo "Price: $row[5]<br><br>";
    echo "<input type='text' name='txtqty' value='1' size=2 maxlength=2>";
    echo "<input type='submit' name='btnadd' value='Add To Cart'
OnClick='SubmitForm'>";
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td><img src='images/products/$row[2]' "
     ."height=300px width =250px></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";

//print_r($row);
}
//4. Release the resources
mysqli_free_result($result);
//5. Close the connection
mysqli_close($dbconn);
?>



</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's the problem? It doesn't update?

Comment: Where is `$row[0]` defined in your statement `$itemid = $_POST[$row[0]];`?

Comment: Your code is also vulnerable to SQL Injection.

Comment: @hzq Right. Shoulda said that. Duh.

Comment: @Twisty I thought it was defined in the code that originally generated the page (right above all the echos near the bottom) but yeah I guess it doesn't work like that, and yeah hopefully this guy teaches us how to seal up the vulnerabilities at some point. He told us not to worry about that for now. I did finally get it running.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<?PHP
print_r($_POST);
if (isset($_GET['prod'])) $prod=$_GET['prod'];
else $prod = "arm01";
 //if (isset($_GET['tab'])) $table= $_GET['tab'];
// else $table="Cart_view02";
//$reset = true;
//$errmsg = array("","");
//1. Make a connection to the database
$dbconn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","mydatabase1") 
      or die(mysqli_connect_error());
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

    $qty = $_POST['txtqty'];
    $crtnum = 100;
    if (preg_match("/^[0-9]{1,2}$/",$qty)){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO cart_lineitems VALUES ($crtnum, '$prod', $qty);";
        $result = mysqli_query($dbconn,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($dbconn));

        //echo"<br>$sql";
         header("location: cartdump.php");
    }
    else echo "Quantity is not valid<br>";
}
?>


<html>
<head><title>Order Page</title>
<link href="css/styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>

<img class="banner" src="Images/acme_banner.jpg" alt="Acme Spook Shoppe"/>

</head>
<body> 
<br><br> 
<a href= "home.php">Home</a>

<form name="form1" method='POST'>
<?php

//echo $prod;   //<------To print results



$sql = "select productid,name,imagefile, "
    ."shortdescription, longdescription,"
    ."unitprice "
    ."from products "
    ."where productid='$prod'";
    echo "<br>";
//echo $sql;    //<------To print results

//2. Run a query against the database
$result = mysqli_query($dbconn,$sql) 
    or die(mysqli_error($dbconn));

    //print_r($result); //<------To print results

//3. Return the results
    echo "<table class=ordertable >";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>$row[1]<br><br>";
    echo "$row[3]<br><br>";
    echo "$row[4]<br><br>";
    echo "Price: $row[5]<br><br>";
    echo "<input type='text' name='txtqty' value='1' size=2 maxlength=2>";
    echo "<input type='submit' name='btnadd' value='Add To Cart' OnClick='SubmitForm'>";
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td><img src='images/products/$row[2]' "
     ."height=300px width =250px></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";

//print_r($row);
}
//4. Release the resources
mysqli_free_result($result);
//5. Close the connection
mysqli_close($dbconn);
?>



</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe you'd want to edit this into your question instead of posting an answer. :)